# Junit ExpectedException: expect an exact Exception object

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

So I have been using the [ExpectedException](http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/4.11/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) to expect a thrown exception's `type`s, `message`s, `cause`s and even `matcher`s.

But why isn't there a utility method to simply expect an exception object completely? Surely, I'd better off testing object equality (assuming I know what I'm doing) rather than testing all its individual attributes? After all, if a `method A` merely throws up any exceptions that its delegator `method B` throws (`method A` calls `method B`), it would be much easier for me to mock `method B` to throw an exception, say `Exception A` and check for the exact object being thrown in my `method A`'s test method?

So why isn't such a utility method provided?

Of course I can wrap my `method A` call in my test and catch the exception to test the object, but the same can be said of `type`s, `message`s and `cause`s too - I'd imagine the objective is to make the test code look a lot more readable that it is w/o the try/catch block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use [`ExpectedException#expect(Matcher)`](http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html#expect%28org.hamcrest.Matcher%29) and provide a `Matcher` that checks reference or object equality. You can use [`org.hamcrest.core.Is#is(Object)`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/hamcrest/core/Is.html#is%28T%29), passing in the exact `Exception` instance it will throw (if that's something you can control).

Comment: Didn't know such a `Matcher` was possible. Checking it out.